# Tranpose columns into rows with bigquery sql

Tags: google-bigquery

i wanted to transpose column into rows

having data like

```
column1 column2 column3 column4
26  null    null    null
14  51      null    null
16  null    null    null
42  null    null    null
41  26      null    null
16  21      41      null
12  21      41      26
12  41      null    null
```

wanted like

```
column
26
14
51
16
42
41
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

A union all approach is one option:

```sql
SELECT val
FROM
(
    SELECT column1 AS val FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT column2 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT column3 FROM yourTable UNION ALL
    SELECT column4 FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE val IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select column
from data
unpivot (column for col in (column1, column2, column3, column4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option

```
select column
from data, unnest([column1, column2, column3, column4]) column
where not column is null
```